# Organize multiple lines of text, every third or second line, depending on initial string variable

Tags: parsing, awk, sed, format, stdout

I have an output of lines generated as such:

> LINES=$(for i in {scsi,sat,ata,nvme}; do smartctl --scan -d $i ; done
> | sort | uniq | grep -v '^#|/dev/sd' | awk '{print$2,$3,$5}' | sed
> 's/,*\r*$//') ; while IFS= read -r line; do smartctl -i $line; done
> <<< "$LINES" | grep -v Family |  grep -e Model -e Product: -e Vendor:
> -e "User Capacity" -e "Total NVM Capacity" | awk -F"[:\t]" '{print$2}'

Giving the following output:

```
           SEAGATE
          ST2000NX0273
    2,000,398,934,016 bytes [2.00 TB]
           SEAGATE
          ST2000NX0273
    2,000,398,934,016 bytes [2.00 TB]
           SEAGATE
          ST2000NX0273
    2,000,398,934,016 bytes [2.00 TB]
           SEAGATE
          ST2000NX0273
    2,000,398,934,016 bytes [2.00 TB]
           SEAGATE
          ST2000NX0273
    2,000,398,934,016 bytes [2.00 TB]
           SEAGATE
          ST2000NX0273
    2,000,398,934,016 bytes [2.00 TB]
 INTEL SSDSC2KB240G7
240,057,409,536 bytes [240 GB]
                   INTEL SSDPE2KX020T7
             2,000,398,934,016 [2.00 TB]
                   INTEL SSDPE2KX020T7
             2,000,398,934,016 [2.00 TB]
```

I'm hoping to put each HDD information into it's own line, while simultaneously parsing the Capacity to display it's human-readable format. It's ok if the capacitt still has [brackets]. Desired output:

```
SEAGATE ST2000NX0273 2.00 TB
SEAGATE ST2000NX0273 2.00 TB
SEAGATE ST2000NX0273 2.00 TB
SEAGATE ST2000NX0273 2.00 TB
SEAGATE ST2000NX0273 2.00 TB
SEAGATE ST2000NX0273 2.00 TB
INTEL SSDSC2KB240G7 240 GB
INTEL SSDPE2KX020T7 2.00 TB
INTEL SSDPE2KX020T7 2.00 TB
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, please do add your efforts in form of code in your question and let us know then, its highly encouraged on SO.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 Hi Ravinder, I've edited to include the original command to generate the output. Suggestions to make this more elegant are also welcome ^_^;;;

Comment: Great, special thanks for adding your efforts in your question, kindly always do the same and keep it up, I have added an answer too cheers.

Comment: You write a command with for loop, while loop, 2 grep, 3 awk,  1 sed, sort, uniq, and smartctl, so that you get a reasonable output, which yes, can be processed with a simple awk command finally. However epic, this way, any small change in your data would break it. If you provide an earlier shape of your data, maybe a lot of these commands could be unified to one, so that you finally have 2-3 commands.

Comment: @thanasisp Yes, you're completely correct, it's a bit of a mess. Unfortunately, it seems the key-value output of smartctl are vendor-decided, thus the mess of grep. Also i wanted to not need to know which drives are actually present, or what defining integer the RAID controller holds them under, so I the initial for loop generates lines for all the existing drives, eliminating the raid-front /dev/sd[a-b], and uses that for the while loop. I'll definitely try to refine it and edit my post. Your response below was simple and elegant, thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk -v RS=[][] '{ORS=(NR%2? " ": "\n"); print $1, $2}' file
```

Testing with your input:

```
> cat file
          SEAGATE
          ST2000NX0273
    2,000,398,934,016 bytes [2.00 TB]
           SEAGATE
          ST2000NX0273
    2,000,398,934,016 bytes [2.00 TB]
           SEAGATE
          ST2000NX0273
    2,000,398,934,016 bytes [2.00 TB]
           SEAGATE
          ST2000NX0273
    2,000,398,934,016 bytes [2.00 TB]
           SEAGATE
          ST2000NX0273
    2,000,398,934,016 bytes [2.00 TB]
           SEAGATE
          ST2000NX0273
    2,000,398,934,016 bytes [2.00 TB]
 INTEL SSDSC2KB240G7
240,057,409,536 bytes [240 GB]
                   INTEL SSDPE2KX020T7
             2,000,398,934,016 [2.00 TB]
                   INTEL SSDPE2KX020T7
             2,000,398,934,016 [2.00 TB]
```

Output:

```
SEAGATE ST2000NX0273 2.00 TB
SEAGATE ST2000NX0273 2.00 TB
SEAGATE ST2000NX0273 2.00 TB
SEAGATE ST2000NX0273 2.00 TB
SEAGATE ST2000NX0273 2.00 TB
SEAGATE ST2000NX0273 2.00 TB
INTEL SSDSC2KB240G7 240 GB
INTEL SSDPE2KX020T7 2.00 TB
INTEL SSDPE2KX020T7 2.00 TB
```

---

Also, the initial approach here, as `]` is the end of every "record", would be something like this:

```
awk -v RS=] '{gsub("\\[",""); print $1, $2, $(NF-1), $NF}' file
```

Comment: If you have the time, can you explain the use a bit more? I understand the Record separator, ORS, and Number of Records, but struggling with the logic...

Comment: yes. We don't split records at newlines but at opening and closing brackets. RS=`[][]` Now, see the input, we have to print only 1st and 2nd field, either it is disk description or capacity. With one more detail: We swap the ORS between space and newline for every record (with that ternary expression NR mod 2) then it is ok.

Comment: you see, it's fragile, e.g. if new disks come with 3 words, would break. Using only the closing bracket is what to do then- and the safier approach also - `-RS=]` and then  you print what you want from every record. E.g. in that case `$(NF-1)` (without that prefix `[` ) and `$NF` would be the capacity

Comment: yes, i see it. playing around with it a bit, even removing the awk command before breaks it. will try my best to bring a better structure and edit my post.

Comment: You should mention that requires GNU awk for multi-char RS.

Answer (score 2):

Could you please try following, written and tested with shown samples only in GNU `awk`.

```
awk -v RS= -v FS="\n" '
{
  while($0){
    match($0,/[^]]*/)
    val=""
    val=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
    gsub(/\n[[:space:]]+|\n/," ",val)
    sub(/^ +/,"",val)
    num=split(val,arr," |\\[")
    print arr[1],arr[2],arr[num-1],arr[num]
    $0=substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH+1)
  }
}'  Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk -v RS= -v FS="\n" '                        ##Starting awk program from here and setting field separator as new line and RS as null.
{
  while($0){                                   ##Running while loop till line exists.
    match($0,/[^]]*/)                          ##Using match function to match everything till ] here.
    val=""                                     ##Nullifying variable val here.
    val=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)              ##Creating val which has sub-string from RSTART to till RLENGTH value.
    gsub(/\n[[:space:]]+|\n/," ",val)          ##Globally substituting either newline spaces OR only new lines with space in val.
    sub(/^ +/,"",val)                          ##Substituting starting spaces with NULL in val here.
    num=split(val,arr," |\\[")                 ##Splitting val value into arr with deliminator of space and [ for all values.
    print arr[1],arr[2],arr[num-1],arr[num]    ##printing 1st, 2nd and 2nd last and last value of arr here.
   $0=substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH+1)              ##Re-creating value of current line which has REST of the line leaving part which was matched above, to skip already matched part and avoid duplicates.
  }
}'  Input_file                                 ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

In case you are running this command by taking output of another commands then pipe this to them like `your_command | awk...` you could remove Input_file from above then.

Comment: Excellent! This does it. And thanks a ton for the explanation! thanasip's answer is more simplified, and workable for my purposes, but there's a lot of value to be gained from yours as well, and it works :D

Answer (score 1):

Using any awk in any shell on every Unix box:

```
$ cat tst.awk
gsub(/.*[[]|[]]/,"") {
    $0 = prev FS $0
    $1 = $1
    print
    prev = ""
    next
}
{ prev = prev FS $0 }
```

.

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
SEAGATE ST2000NX0273 2.00 TB
SEAGATE ST2000NX0273 2.00 TB
SEAGATE ST2000NX0273 2.00 TB
SEAGATE ST2000NX0273 2.00 TB
SEAGATE ST2000NX0273 2.00 TB
SEAGATE ST2000NX0273 2.00 TB
INTEL SSDSC2KB240G7 240 GB
INTEL SSDPE2KX020T7 2.00 TB
INTEL SSDPE2KX020T7 2.00 TB
```